# How to apply an image as the color for a text made with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Here's a generic text canvas:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 85;
var y = 65;

context.font = '40pt Calibri';
context.lineWidth = 3;
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.strokeText('This is my text', x, y);
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.fillText('This is my text', x, y);
```

How can I create that text with an image as its `strokeStyle` and `fillStyle` instead of black or whatever color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After filling the text on canvas, change composite mode:

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';  /// or source-atop
```

Then draw the image over the text and the text only will be replaced with the image.

Comment: What if I also want to add a border around the text?

Comment: @dabadaba just run a strokeText afterwards (after resetting composite mode to `source-over`)

Answer (score 1):

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ApaJoWIk/2/edit)***

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    cw = canvas.width,
    ch = canvas.height,
    x = 85,
    y = 65,
    img = new Image();

function txt2img() {
  context.font = '40pt Calibri';
  context.fillText('This is my text', x, y);  
  context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, cw, ch);
}

img.onload = txt2img;
img.src = "image.jpg";
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an example at [MDN - Applying styles and colors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors#A_createPattern_example). Applied to your text

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100';
img.onload = function () {
    // create pattern
    var ptrn = context.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
    context.fillStyle = ptrn;
    context.fillText('This is my text', x, y);
}
```

See full [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TMLsL/)